# Preventing shapes from overflow + positioning?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a component where there is a hollow circle that is cropped at the bottom-left corner:

[image: element with hollow circle at the bottom-left corner]

I've attempted to do so with the pseudo classes below but am facing two issues after working with it for a while (dimensions of the circle are not the same, but I will address this later):

1. The circles overflow outside of the component
2. The positioning of the circles changes depending on where the element is used.

```css
#element {
  max-width: 750px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #008001;
}

#element:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #008001;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 290px;
  right: 94%;
}

#element:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 260px;
  right: 92%;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set `overflow:hidden` to `#element`. SO `we can hide overflowing content of `::before` CSS. Also set `#element` to `position:relative`, which set's boundary for `::before` when we try to set it after making it `absolute`.
- Once above =e things are done, just apply `#element::before` to `bottom:-50px` and `left:-50px`, I have used `50px` as height and width were set to `100px`.
- Then to get the border just set `border:25px solid #yourolor`.

```css
#element {
  max-width: 750px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #008001;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#element:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 4;
  background: #008001;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 25px solid #c5ffc6;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: Solved all the issues. Setting the parent to relative and the child to absolute makes sense!